# reverse a pointer read from binary file

Tags: c, swap, endianness

I'm trying to reverse some pointers that were read from a binary encoded file.

When I try to reverse the pointer 0xfffe0024540 stored in big endian format, I get 
0xffffffffe0024540

The pointer is stored in the file in the format:
0000 ff0f 02e0 4045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of right-shifting a negative signed integer is implementation dependent,
as far as I remember. You should replace `long` by `unsigned long` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: Right. I'd gotten languages switched, but sign-extension does indeed seem to be the root issue.

Comment: So, I tried replacing long by uint64_t but it still returns the same result.

Comment: @gary: Can you add a self-contained example demonstrating the problem to your question? Because `0xffffffffe0024540` is just the sign-extension of `0xfffe0024540`, without *any* swapped bytes. So there must be another problem ... (Btw. I tested the code on a Mac and it worked. What platform are you on?)

Comment: I'm running it on linux(OpenSUSE)

Comment: @gary: without an example including the printf's showing the problem it is difficult to help. (But it is late now where I live, so I will probably not respond before tomorrow.)

Comment: @gary: The swap function should be declared as `uint64_t swapPtr(uint64_t value)`. - I have tested your code (on Mac OS X) with a data file containing "00 00 ff 0f 02 e0 40 45"`, and the output was "pointer: 0xff0f02e04045". Perhaps you can show the contents of the pointer before swapping if you get a different result.